# Character Mode settings in macOSTerminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I have an old-school text-based Citadel BBS running in DOSBox on a Raspberry Pi Zero, accessible via telnet at anthropocene.sytes.net:13000. It runs smoothly for callers using PuTTY (with line editing mode forced off) from Windows and Linux, or ConnectBot from Android.

When macOS callers using Terminal or iTerm hit return, it appears to send the return twice. Best guess is macOS handles character mode in a nonstandard way. Several knowledgeable users have delved into their settings looking to configure character mode without luck. Even VT100 emulation didn't resolve the problem.

Is there a way to access character mode settings in macOS? Or might the double CR/LF issue be caused by something else unique to macOS?

Comment: I get the same duplication of whatever your BBS sends me (and whatever I send) if I use telnet on Linux (debian). So it seems to be a general issue regarding telnet and your BBS setup, not just macOS specific.

Comment: I've also tried telnet://bbs.slumberland.org (which is Citadel based as well), works quite well, without duplication.